# 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, datetime

Есть такой код на проверку комментариев.

```
if user.last_comment <= datetime.now():
    user.balance += 4
    user.last_comment = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=3)
    user.save()
    await user.reply(f'{user.mention()}, награда за коментарий +4 <3.', only_user=True)

else:
    time = datetime.now() - user.last_comment
    await user.reply(f'{user.mention()}, вы уже оставляли коментарий! Попробуйте через {time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")}', only_user=True)
```

При написании комментария бот крашится и пишет в консоль

`'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объект `timedelta`, который представляет собой, в частности, разность двух дат, не имеет метода `strftime`. Поэтому вывести его можно в виде стандартного строкового представления `str(time)` >> `7:08:59.760949` (с микросекундами) либо отформатировать самостоятельно. Три варианта ниже.

```
import datetime

time = int((datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 9, 12, 15, 18)).total_seconds())
print(f'вы уже оставляли комментарий {time // 3600}:{time // 60 % 60:02d}:{time % 60:02d} назад')

time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 9, 12, 15, 18)
print(f'вы уже оставляли комментарий {str(time).split(".")[0]} назад')

time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 9, 12, 15, 18)
print(f'вы уже оставляли комментарий {datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(time.total_seconds()))} назад')
```

```
вы уже оставляли комментарий 7:05:56 назад
вы уже оставляли комментарий 7:05:56 назад
вы уже оставляли комментарий 7:05:56 назад
```